# В предложении ошибки есть?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Информации о проблематике по вопросу действий организаций, а также законодательные предложения отсутствуют.

Answer (score 2):

Единственная: слово "информация" не имеет множественного числа. Ога, исчо - речевая избыточность: проблематика по вопросу! по вопросу действий!

Пунктуация на месте.

*Информация о проблемах в действиях организаций, а также законодательные предложения отсутствуют*.

Формально всё верно я  Вам нарисовала, смыслово - проблематичны *проблемы в действиях*, но так можно досокращать до нуля...